# Disable enter keypad for 3 seconds after first press and re-enable the enter keypad again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code but I am having challenges on how to go about it. I want to disable enter keypad for three seconds after the first press and re-enable it again. This is my attempt

```
    function disableForThreeSeconds(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //if pressed for the first disable for three seconds
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly assist!

Comment: Are you trying to disable it for the entire page or for specific element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In if block:

```
e.target.disabled = true;   
window.setTimeout(function(){
    e.target.disabled = false;
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout`. Look documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Api:
`number setTimeout(function callback, integer milliseconds )`

Simple jQuery example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(window).keypress(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            return false;
        }
    })
}, 3000);
```

Comment: This is going to disable the key _after_ three seconds. And it's going to stay disabled.

Comment: @Francis, this is a "simple" example. You need learn about `setTimeout` and apply you code under it. "I can teach and guide, but not do the work".

Comment: @OlafErlandsen Every 3 seconds you are setting an event listener that goes to disable the function of the enter key. Once you set the event, there is nothing that stops it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the keypad you can just ignore the events in your handler...

```
var isDisabled;

function disableForThreeSeconds(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if (!isDisabled) {
            isDisabled = new Date();
        } else {
        //if pressed for the first disable for three seconds
            if (new Date() - isDisabled > 3 * 1000 )
                isDisabled = 0;
        }
    }
}
```